# How to put Recently Viewed Product on the top of Page Footer

Tags: layout, widget, magento2

I am new in Magento (2) development, I want to positioning the "Recently Viewed" on the top of footer (on the bottom of content section).

As you can see here, it always shown on the top of content area:

[image]

What I want is to placed it exactly on the top of footer.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: U can find  in PDP/PLP page layout recently view block...just update the position wr ever u required

Comment: Hi, could you please explain more about that ? what is PDP/PLP ?

Comment: In which page you want to get recently view block?

Comment: on the home page, on the top of Footer

Comment: did u have any idea about how blocks will load?

Comment: refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199889/magento-2-2-0-display-recently-viewed-products-block-on-product-detail-page

Answer (score 0):

move this recently viewed your block above the footer.

Open/Create below file

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

add this code

```
<move element="Your-block-name" destination="content.aside" before="page.footer"/>
```

Flush your cache!